# Who is owner of code under GPL3?

Tags: gpl, gpl-3, ownership

In the header of GPLv3 wrote `Copyright ... Free Software Foundation`

```
                    GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
                       Version 3, 29 June 2007

 Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc. <https://fsf.org/>
 Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies
 of this license document, but changing it is not allowed.
```

What does it mean? A code under this license owned by FSF? Or it's my code (if I'm author). Which role has FSF in a project under GLP3?

```
// Project name 
// Copyright (C) 2019  My name 
//  
// This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify 
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by 
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or 
// (at your option) any later version. 
//  
// This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, 
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of 
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the 
// GNU General Public License for more details. 
//  
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License 
// along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
```

Is it valid header for a file to save my copyright. Can I use the `Copyright (C) year My name` only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The copyright and license headers you quote in your first segment pertain only to "this license document" -- i.e., the text of the GPLv3 itself -- and not to any external work that might be made available by others under the terms described in that license document. In short, licensing a work under the GPL does not impact your own copyright of your work; you retain copyright ownership by default (unless you proactively assign it to someone else or it belongs to your employer).

Some related concepts that might have confused you:

- For legal reasons, [the FSF only accepts contributions to its own projects if the author of a contribution assigns the copyright to the FSF](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-assign.en.html). This is a policy decision by the FSF and is not required by the GPL. Many GPL-licensed projects do not require copyright assignment and allow authors to keep the copyright on their contributions, resulting in a project with heterogeneous copyright ownership uniformly licensed under the GPL.
- Despite the fact that the header of the GPL does not allow modified versiona of the GPL text, the FSF separately [does give that permission in its GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#ModifyGPL), provided you change the name of your modified license and omit the preamble.

Comment: Thanks, GPL3 header has `...under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation...` (the second paragraph). Does it mean GPL published by FSF or my program if I insert it?

Comment: Try reading it as `under the terms of (the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation)`.  That is to say, it's the GPL that is so published.

Comment: @Wootiae The identifier "GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation" attempts to identify the relevant family of licenses as precisely as possible (i.e., applicable version(s) of the FSF's GNU GPL)